# Puppet missing deprecation warnings

Tags: logging, puppet

I'm running a Puppet 3.4.3 master which I use to provision VMs.

I noticed that a lot of deprecation warnings I can see when provisioning locally are missing when using the server as master. (For example that a hiera file hasn't been found and defaults are being used)

Using the debug or verbose option didn't help either.
The strange thing is that I found some warnings regarding deprecated variable names in the apt module in the master's syslog.

However other warnings about missing the '@' symbol in front of ruby variable names are nowhere to be found.

I tried raising the log level inside the master's puppet.conf to debug but it didn't change anything.

What am I missing?

Config print:

```
agent_catalog_run_lockfile = /var/lib/puppet/state/agent_catalog_run.lock
agent_disabled_lockfile = /var/lib/puppet/state/agent_disabled.lock
allow_duplicate_certs = false
allow_variables_with_dashes = false
archive_file_server = puppet
archive_files = false
async_storeconfigs = false
autoflush = true
autosign = /etc/puppet/autosign.conf
binder = false
binder_config = 
bucketdir = /var/lib/puppet/bucket
ca = true
ca_port = 8140
ca_server = puppet
ca_ttl = 157680000
cacert = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem
cacrl = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crl.pem
cadir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca
cakey = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_key.pem
capass = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/private/ca.pass
caprivatedir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/private
capub = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_pub.pem
catalog_cache_terminus = 
catalog_format = ""
catalog_terminus = compiler
cert_inventory = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/inventory.txt
certdir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs
certdnsnames = ""
certificate_expire_warning = 5184000
certificate_revocation = true
classfile = /var/lib/puppet/state/classes.txt
client_datadir = /var/lib/puppet/client_data
clientbucketdir = /var/lib/puppet/clientbucket
clientyamldir = /var/lib/puppet/client_yaml
code = ""
color = ansi
confdir = /etc/puppet
config = /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
config_file_name = puppet.conf
config_version = ""
configprint = all
configtimeout = 120
csr_attributes = /etc/puppet/csr_attributes.yaml
csrdir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/requests
daemonize = true
data_binding_terminus = hiera
dbadapter = sqlite3
dbconnections = ""
dblocation = /var/lib/puppet/state/clientconfigs.sqlite3
dbmigrate = false
dbname = puppet
dbpassword = puppet
dbport = ""
dbserver = localhost
dbsocket = ""
dbuser = puppet
default_file_terminus = rest
default_schedules = true
deviceconfig = /etc/puppet/device.conf
devicedir = /var/lib/puppet/devices
diff = diff
diff_args = -u
document_all = false
dynamicfacts = memorysize,memoryfree,swapsize,swapfree
environment = production
evaltrace = false
external_nodes = none
factpath = /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter
facts_terminus = yaml
fileserverconfig = /etc/puppet/fileserver.conf
filetimeout = 15
freeze_main = false
genconfig = false
genmanifest = false
graph = false
graphdir = /var/lib/puppet/state/graphs
group = puppet
hiera_config = /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml
http_compression = false
http_proxy_host = none
http_proxy_port = 3128
httplog = /var/log/puppet/http.log
ignorecache = false
ignoreimport = false
ignoremissingtypes = false
ignoreschedules = false
inventory_port = 8140
inventory_server = puppet
inventory_terminus = yaml
keylength = 4096
lastrunfile = /var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml
lastrunreport = /var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml
ldapattrs = all
ldapbase = ""
ldapclassattrs = puppetclass
ldapparentattr = parentnode
ldappassword = ""
ldapport = 389
ldapserver = ldap
ldapssl = false
ldapstackedattrs = puppetvar
ldapstring = (&(objectclass=puppetClient)(cn=%s))
ldaptls = false
ldapuser = ""
legacy_query_parameter_serialization = false
libdir = /var/lib/puppet/lib
listen = false
localcacert = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem
localconfig = /var/lib/puppet/state/localconfig
logdir = /var/log/puppet
manage_internal_file_permissions = true
manifest = /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp
manifestdir = /etc/puppet/manifests
masterhttplog = /var/log/puppet/masterhttp.log
masterlog = /var/log/puppet/puppetmaster.log
masterport = 8140
max_deprecations = 10000
max_errors = 10
max_warnings = 10000
maximum_uid = 4294967290
mkusers = false
module_repository = https://forge.puppetlabs.com
module_skeleton_dir = /var/lib/puppet/puppet-module/skeleton
module_working_dir = /var/lib/puppet/puppet-module
modulepath = /etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
name = master
node_cache_terminus = write_only_yaml
node_name = cert
node_name_fact = ""
node_terminus = plain
noop = false
onetime = false
ordering = title-hash
parser = current
path = none
pidfile = /var/run/puppet/master.pid
plugindest = /var/lib/puppet/lib
pluginfactdest = /var/lib/puppet/facts.d
pluginfactsource = puppet://puppet/pluginfacts
pluginsignore = .svn CVS .git
pluginsource = puppet://puppet/plugins
pluginsync = true
postrun_command = /etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-post
preferred_serialization_format = pson
prerun_command = /etc/puppet/etckeeper-commit-pre
priority = 
privatedir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private
privatekeydir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys
profile = false
publickeydir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/public_keys
puppetdlog = /var/log/puppet/puppetd.log
puppetport = 8139
queue_type = stomp
rails_loglevel = info
railslog = /var/log/puppet/rails.log
report = true
report_port = 8140
report_serialization_format = pson
report_server = puppet
reportdir = /var/lib/puppet/reports
reports = store
req_bits = 4096
requestdir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests
resourcefile = /var/lib/puppet/state/resources.txt
rest_authconfig = /etc/puppet/auth.conf
route_file = /etc/puppet/routes.yaml
rrddir = /var/lib/puppet/rrd
rrdinterval = 1800
rundir = /var/run/puppet
runinterval = 1800
sendmail = ""
serial = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/serial
server = puppet
server_datadir = /var/lib/puppet/server_data
show_diff = false
signeddir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/signed
smtpport = 25
smtpserver = none
splay = false
splaylimit = 1800
ssl_client_ca_auth = 
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
ssl_server_ca_auth = 
ssldir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl
statedir = /var/lib/puppet/state
statefile = /var/lib/puppet/state/state.yaml
storeconfigs = false
storeconfigs_backend = active_record
strict_hostname_checking = false
stringify_facts = true
summarize = false
syslogfacility = daemon
tagmap = /etc/puppet/tagmail.conf
tags = ""
templatedir = /etc/puppet/templates
thin_storeconfigs = false
trace = false
trusted_node_data = false
use_cached_catalog = false
use_srv_records = false
usecacheonfailure = true
user = puppet
vardir = /var/lib/puppet
waitforcert = 120
yamldir = /var/lib/puppet/yaml
zlib = true
```

Comment: There's a limit to the number of deprecation warnings that a master will emit. Have you tried restarting apache/puppetmaster and watching the logs right after that?

Comment: Yes, got the same result as before. I even set the [max_deprecations and max_errors](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/configuration.html#maxdeprecations) variables inside my puppet.conf to a huge number, I'm not sure if it works with 3.4.3 though

Comment: Okay it's the same for 3.4.3 http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/configuration.html#maxdeprecations

Comment: Can you supply the output of `puppet master --configprint all` on the master machine, invoked as root?

Comment: Sorry for the late update, added the config settings

Comment: I cleared up some configurations and I think all deprecation warnings now show up in the master's syslog.